# Gerrit asks for rebase when tried to submit change

Tags: gerrit

I am using gerrit for code review. While merging changes I get error like "rebase you change". I think its because of parent changes. I wan to know what is the parent(s) in this case. And how gerrit decides which should be parent commit for any change uploaded for review?

Answer (score 1):

Usually the parent will be the current "master" (HEAD). So you have to retrieve your change using the commands shown in gerrit. Then do a:

```
git rebase master
```

to rebase your change to current master.

If this goes well (and after eventually calling "`git rebase --continue`") you can push your rebased change to gerrit by using:

```
git push origin HEAD:refs/for/master
```